# What does testenv stand for?

Tags: test-environments

A programming document I have is constantly referring to "testenv". What could it possibly mean? It's used in the following example:

> Testenv will be used proactively with production to ensure concurrent stability and analysis

Comment: Maybe test environment as opposed to productino environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A test environment usually means that the whole system is duplicated with its own database and must not interfere with production data. You should be careful because of "used proactively with production". You should learn more about the configuration before you use this environment.